# How to drill into a 5/8” edge?

Tags: woodworking

I’m trying to follow these following day bed plans: https://www.ana-white.com/woodworking-projects/simple-daybed and I’m trying to attach the bed frame to the posts. It looks to call for screwing the 75 3/4” 2x2 into the post but there’s only a 5/8” clearance.

5/8” just doesn’t seem large enough to me. And even if it was, how would I get the drill in there and to be straight?  I was hoping someone out there could help untangle this mystery for me

Comment: Doesn't make much sense to me to have a screw so close to the end of the 2x2. Doesn't seem like it'll provide any real support without just breaking the wood.

Comment: That’s what I was thinking too. I don’t really get the plans. I was thinking of working around this by using some corner brackets to provide support. Would that work instead?

Comment: My guess is that it is not really for support and it just helps hold the end on while building. Manual screwdriver should allow turning a screw in a tight space; predrill the hole before putting in place if you want to follow the instructions.